# javascript: how to show formatted timestamp w.r.t UTC timezome

Tags: javascript, datetime

Curently i am working in GMT+0530 timezone

```
new Date()
Fri Mar 06 2020 11:29:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Now i am trying to format it as i need

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' })+' '+today.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' })+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time+' '+today.getFullYear();
```

Time is stored as follows

`Fri Mar-6 11:22:4 2020`

Now how to get the UTC time in the same format

Comment: @Santosh Yedidi , may be try momentjs : A lightweight (4.3k) javascript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using *toLocaleString* with options, just specify the timezone as UTC and also use UTC methods for the day and time, e.g.

```js
var today = new Date();
var date = today.toLocaleString('default', {weekday: 'short', timeZone:'UTC'}) + ' ' +
           today.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'short', timeZone:'UTC'}) + '-' +
           today.toLocaleString('default', {day: '2-digit', timeZone:'UTC'});
// var time = today.getUTCHours() + ":" + today.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + today.getUTCSeconds();
var time = today.toLocaleString('default',{hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit', hour12:false, timeZone:'UTC'});
var year = today.toLocaleString('default',{year:'numeric', timeZone:'UTC'});
var dateTime = date + ' ' + time + ' ' + year;

console.log(dateTime);
```

Comment: in `toLocaleString` :: `{ weekday: 'short', timeZone:'UTC'}` thats what i was thinking of how to implement timezome

Answer (score 2):

You can get the offset between your timezone and UTC, then create a `new Date` with the added offset and format it as you did previously.

```js
var localToday = new Date();
var offset = localToday.getTimezoneOffset();
var today = new Date(localToday.getTime() + (offset * 60 * 1000));
var date = today.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' })+' '+today.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' })+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time+' '+today.getFullYear();
console.log(dateTime);
```

Comment: This will likely get the wrong time where the offset crosses a daylight saving boundary. It's also unnecessary if the timezone is set to UTC in *toLocaleString*.

Comment: `getTimezoneOffset()` accounts for DST. Where daylight savings are used you can verify it with `console.log(new Date(2020, 0, 1).getTimezoneOffset());
console.log(new Date(2020, 6, 1).getTimezoneOffset());`

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. When adjusting a Date by the offset this way, it can take the local time into or out of daylight saving, so a different offset is applied in your code to that used to determine the offset for *get\** methods.

Comment: I fail to see the problem, could you give an example date and/or timezone that gives different result in your answer compared to mine?

Comment: Set your system to a place with daylight saving. Start with a Date and time where adding the timezone offset will move it across the daylight saving boundary. Now check the date and time your function returns to the actual UTC date and time of the unadjusted date. It will be different by the DST offset (typically 1 hour or 30 minutes in some places).

Answer (score 0):

Try using moment-js. It has got wide variety of flags to format the way you want.

Working sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-cdn-yp5mb

```
const moment = require("moment");
console.log(moment.utc().format('ddd MMM-D YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

Comment: An answer shouldn't depend on a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP. Otherwise there could an answer for every date formatting library available (which is quite a few).

Comment: @RobG, Just gave OP an alternative. Did not tell this is perfect. Cheers:)